# objective c - for loop to fetch image from iCloud sequentially

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous

on IOS, I need to get metadata for a selected set of images. But since the images are backed up to iCloud, sometimes it may immediately return (cached) and sometimes it may take a second or two.

The for loop runs through quickly, I am able to wait for all of the images to be processed before I move forward. But they still are being fetched in parallel. How do I make the for loop run sequentially by waiting for the block to finish before moving on to next image.

```
// Step 4: Fetch Details like Metadata for this batch
-(void) getDetailsForThisBatchOfNewAssets:(NSMutableArray*) mArrBatchOfNewAssets
                    withCompletionHandler:(blockReturnsMArrAndMArr) blockReturns{

    NSLog(@"%s with arraySize of %lu",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, (unsigned long)[mArrBatchOfNewAssets count] );

    long assetCount = [mArrBatchOfNewAssets count];

    NSMutableArray *mArrNewAssetsAndDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *mArrNewAssetFailed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if(assetCount == 0){

        NSLog(@" Looks like there are no NEW media files on the device.");
        return;
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"found %ld assets in all that need to be backed up", assetCount);

    dispatch_group_t groupForLoopGetDetails = dispatch_group_create();

    for(long i = 0 ; i < assetCount; i++){

        PHAsset *currentAsset = [[mArrBatchOfNewAssets objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"asset"];

        NSString *mediaIdentifier = [[[currentAsset localIdentifier] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] firstObject];
        [mArrIdentifiersInThisBatch addObject:mediaIdentifier];

        dispatch_group_enter(groupForLoopGetDetails);

        [mediaManager getDetailedRecordForAsset:currentAsset
                  withCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableDictionary *mDicDetailedRecord, NSMutableDictionary *mDicRecordForError)
        {
              if(mDicRecordForError[@"error"]){
                  [mArrNewAssetFailed addObject:mDicRecordForError];

                  NSLog(@"Position %ld - Failed to fetch Asset with LocalIdentifier: %@, adding it to Failed Table. Record: %@",i,[currentAsset localIdentifier], mDicRecordForError);

              } else {
                  [mArrNewAssetsAndDetails addObject:mDicDetailedRecord ];

                  NSLog(@"Position %ld - added asset with LocalIdentifier to mArrNewAssetsAndDetails %@",i,[currentAsset localIdentifier]);
              }

            dispatch_group_leave(groupForLoopGetDetails);
        }];
    }   // end of for loop that iterates through each asset.

    dispatch_group_notify(groupForLoopGetDetails, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        NSLog(@"Completed gathering details for this batch of assets for backup. Count : %lu and failed Media count: %lu",(unsigned long)[mArrNewAssetsAndDetails count], (unsigned long)[mArrNewAssetFailed count]);

            blockReturns(mArrNewAssetsAndDetails,mArrNewAssetFailed);
    });

}
```

I have looked through several questions on SO on this topic but still have not figured out how to make this run sequentially.

I don't want to do a "self call" for this method, because I'm already doing "self call" at another place before I reach this method and my code is now growing into too many notifications and catches because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the completion handler of `getDetailedRecordForAsset` is called on a different thread, you can use a semaphore to *block execution (Note: DO NOT DO this on the main thread)* inside the loop while waiting for the completion handler.

Remove the dispatch group stuff, then, inside the loop:

- create a semaphore right before calling `getDetailedRecordForAsset` like so: `dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create( 0);`
- as the last statement of the completion handler call `dispatch_semaphore_signal( semaphore);`
- immediately after calling `getDetailedRecordForAsset`, wait for the end of the completion handler with `dispatch_semaphore_wait( semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);`

So the structure of the loop will look like:

```
for (assets)
{
    ... // get current asset, media identifier as above

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create( 0);

    [mediaManager getDetailedRecordForAsset:currentAsset
              withCompletionHandler:^(NSMutableDictionary *mDicDetailedRecord, NSMutableDictionary *mDicRecordForError)
        {
            ... // handle error or add asset details as above

            dispatch_semaphore_signal( semaphore);
        }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait( semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NoHalfBits. I'll give this a shot. I think I tried this on the main thread last week and it didn't work. This time, like you said, I'll try in background thread and report soon.

Comment: Note that with semaphores you really have to be careful to avoid deadlocking; make sure the completion handler can never ever be scheduled on the thread that is waiting for the semaphore. I would still very much recommend using a block/serial queue based approach, but you explicitly asked to avoid that... i think it's safe to consider this kind of use of semaphores as a dirty hack.